# Media queries on login.min.css

Tags: wordpress, media-queries

My wp-login is customized by me and i want to be able to view it on ipad and iphone. I tried to add it to my options.css file and add the media queries to login.min.css file but nothing happens. what am i doing wrong?

the url is http://thetrashedvintage.com/wp-login.php

this is how it looks on iphone: http://postimg.org/image/n5va3urgv/

Thanks!

Comment: There are 24 CSS files being loaded on that screen... Is that on your radar? What are you doing to customise the CSS?

Comment: Was not aware of that, it looks like all plugins CSS are being loaded. To customise the CSS I included the classes in the options.css and style.css files.

Comment: Pretty dumb plugins if they are spilling their files where not needed :/ Have you read [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form)? This [search query](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=login_enqueue_scripts) may help too.